Create Test Case Result using Azure DevOps API
I am using the api url POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=7.1  which is mentioned on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#testsubresult
to create a test case result
i am creating the result using the TestCaseResult[] and successfully being able to see the result on azure devops
the only problem is that i am not able to get the details part filled in any way. I have the stack trace filled, the error message filled.. but the details should show the steps executed which would be shown in case i am creating a bug from this

This is the code i am using:
listOf(
    TestCaseResultRequestBody(
                    automatedTestName = testCaseResult.title,
                    testRun = ShallowReferenceString(testRunId),
                    durationInMs = testCaseResult.testCaseResult.duration.toMillis(),
                    state = "Completed",
                    outcome = testCaseResult.status.lowercase().capitalize(),
                    testCase = ShallowReference(testCaseResult.workItemMeta.Id.toInt(), name = testCaseResult.annotatedTitle),
                    testPlan = ShallowReferenceString(testPlanId),
                    testPoint = ShallowReferenceString(testPointId),
                    testCaseRevision = testCaseResult.workItemMeta.Revision.toInt(),
                    testCaseTitle = testCaseResult.annotatedTitle,
                    comment = "test",
                    stackTrace =  testCaseResult.stackTrace,
                    errorMessage = if (testCaseResult.failureMessage.isEmpty()) {
                        null
                    } else {
                        val failure = testCaseResult.steps.map {
                            "${it.status.name}: "+it.stepDescription
                        }.joinToString("\n")
                        failure
                    }
                )
            }
    )
            val jsonPayload =  JsonConfig.json.encodeToString(ListSerializer(TestCaseResultRequestBody.serializer()), testCaseResults)
    
            val client = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
            val request = httpRequestBuilder("$AZURE_BASE_URL/test/runs/$testRunId/results?api-version=7.1")

                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonPayload))
                .build()
    
            val response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())



Can you see the "details part" in the test result file uploaded by you? 2. "but the details should show the steps executed which would be shown in case i am creating a bug from this" Can you get the expected result when do it manually? If you can, please share screenshots of what it should look like and what it looks like now to help us understand.

